# How to create a log in form using range

Tags: excel, vba

i am having a problem selecting the range

this is for vba

```
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("admin").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow

    If Sheets("admin").Cells(i, "A").Value = (Me.TextBox1) Then
        Sheets("admin").Select
        Me.TextBox1.Value = Sheets("admin").Cells(i, "A2").Value

        Sheets("Interface").Select
        Sheets("Menu").Visible = True
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
        Sheets("Menu").Select


        Sheet6.User.Enabled = True
    End If
Next i
```

i am expecting to have each role to access a certain sheets

Comment: The following line seems incorrect `Sheets("admin").Cells(i, "A2").Value` as you have the variable i in conjunction with a full range A2, should it not be `Sheets("admin").Cells(i, "A").Value` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following might help you, I've removed the unnecessary select statement and altered your code ever so slightly:

```
Sub Example()
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("admin").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

    If Sheets("admin").Cells(i, "A").Value = (Me.TextBox1) Then
        Me.TextBox1.Value = Sheets("admin").Cells(i, "B").Value 
 'check if you want the value on column B, amend as required
 'it doesn't make sense to check whether Column A = Me.TextBox1 and then pass the 
 'value from TextBox1 to Column A again...

        Sheets("Interface").Visible = xlSheetHidden 'or xlSheetVeryHidden
        Sheets("Menu").Visible = True
        Sheets("Menu").Select

        Sheet6.User.Enabled = True
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```